# Error: Ambiguous class occurrence "Ord"

Tags: haskell, hugs

```
data (Ord a) => Stree a = Null 
| Fork (Stree a) a (Stree a)

mkStree :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Stree a
mkStree [] = Null
mkStree (x:xs) = Fork (mkStree smaller) x (mkStree larger)
               where (smaller,larger) = partition (<= x) xs                    
partition :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
partition p xs = ([ x | x <- xs, p x],
                  [ y | y <- xs, (not . p) y])
```

how can i fix this failure --> Ambiguous class occurrence "Ord"
*** Could refer to: Hugs.Prelude.Ord

Comment: Which line gives you that error? The `data` line? The `mkStree` line? Both?

Comment: This code does not appear to have any type errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error, but I can take some guesses.  The "Ambiguous class occurrence" error means that there is more than one definition of "Ord" in scope, so the real problem is not in the code you've included here.  The problem is either that one of the modules you're importing redefines "Ord" for some reason, or you're redefining it in your code.  Either way, the only way that can work is if other definitions (such as the default one in the Prelude) are hidden or qualified.  If you're trying to use a non-standard Ord implementation, you'll need to import the Prelude hiding Ord:

```
import Prelude hiding(Ord)
```

If you're not intentionally using a non-standard Ord, then you'll need to figure out where the second one is coming from and remove or hide it.  There's not enough information in your question for me to be able to say how to do so, though.  I would expect the error message is also longer than what you've listed here, as it should show the location of both definitions of Ord.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove the Ord context from the data declaration?

```
data Stree a = Null | Fork (Stree a) a (Stree a)
```

Class contexts on data declarations are pretty non-intuitive, and I suspect that may be causing Hugs to error.

In any case, you shouldn't put contexts on data or newtype declarations.  They're useful with certain GHC extensions, but I don't think Hugs supports any of those cases.

Comment: There's strong sentiment to remove class contexts on data decls in an upcoming version of haskell-prime as well.

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see them officially changed to the semantics GHC's developers gave for class contexts on GADT constructors (where the context is required for construction and reintroduced by pattern matching).